# Unable to View Storage Details in azure storage account : Total Data Stored, Blob, and Container Counts Not Visible

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

My Azure Storage account is not displaying the values for Total data stored, number of blobs, number of containers, etc., despite data being saved in it. How can I troubleshoot this issue?

Image is attached below:

[image]

Comment: We can't able to access the image.

Comment: Could you please include more points in question?

Comment: I have attached image for reference . please check

Comment: have you tried any powershell script to get the size of blobs?

Comment: I have not tried any script yet. If any can share

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unable to view storage details in Azure storage account: Total data stored, blob, and container counts not visible.

In the storage browser, there is a line:

> The data provided is regularly updated about 2-4 times a day and published hourly. If your account has extremely large objects, it may be over a day between updates.

It takes time to reflect or update the data in the storage browser panel.

If you need to view storage details in Azure storage account: total data stored, blob, and container, you can follow the steps below:

***Portal -> storage account -> monitoring -> metrics -> scope=yourstorageaccount -> metric namespace= blob -> you can get the required fields like blob count, blob container count, capacity.***

The same applies to file share, table, and queue.

**Portal:**
[image]

In the above image, it shows my blob container count.

> I have not tried any script yet. If anyone can share

If you need a script, you can refer to this [MS-document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/scripts/storage-blobs-container-calculate-size-powershell#sample-script).

**Reference:**

[Storage account used capacity showing incorrect in portal compared to actual used capacity - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1375182/storage-account-used-capacity-showing-incorrect-in) by Niket Kumar Singh.