how to create a scrip in Automation Account to fetch Quotas and Used Capacity for every fileshare
I have been trying to write script in Powershell for Azure Automation Aaccount.
It should be able to:

Get lists of Fileshares in Storage Account
Get total Quota used for every Fileshare
Get Used capacity and display all those data into screen.

This is what I got so far:
# Import the required Azure modules
Import-Module Az.Accounts
Import-Module Az.Storage
Import-Module Az.Resources

# # Authenticate to Azure
# $connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
# $servicePrincipalConnection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName
# Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint

# Variables
$env:AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING = "zzzzzzz"
$resourceGroupName = "vvvvv"
$storageAccountName = "bbbbb"
$subscriptionId = "mmmm"
$resourceGroupName =  "nnnn"
$storageAccountName =  "iiiii"
$storageAccountKey = "wwwwww"
 
# Manage identity check
$connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=$storageAccountName;AccountKey=$storageAccountKey;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"


# Get the storage account context
$storageAccount = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey
# $storageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $storageAccountName
$storageContext = $storageAccount.Context

# Get the list of file shares
$fileShares = az storage share list --account-name $storageAccountName --query "[].name" -o tsv


# Loop through each file share and retrieve quota and usage
foreach ($shareName in $fileShares) {
    # Get the file share properties using Azure CLI
    $shareProperties = az storage share show --name $shareName --account-name $storageAccountName --query "{quota:properties.quota, usage:properties.usage}" -o json | ConvertFrom-Json

    $quotaGB = $shareProperties.quota
    $usedCapacityBytes = $shareProperties.usage
    $usedCapacityGB = [math]::Round($usedCapacityBytes / 1GB, 2)

    # Output the results
    Write-Output "File Share: $shareName"
    Write-Output "Quota (GB): $quotaGB"
    Write-Output "Used Capacity (GB): $usedCapacityGB"
    Write-Output "-----------------------------"
}

Problem is I cannot get Used capacity to screen. It always says :0.
Over investigation I have found that:

Azure CLI and Azure Storage PowerShell modules do not directly provide
used capacity for file shares through a simple API call.
To achieve this, you might need to:
List the files and directories in the file share. Calculate the total
size of all files and directories.

Couple of questions:

Can you help to modify above script?
Is there any restictions in API for storage account to get this data?
Should I enable any additional metrics to get this data?


Refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77905303/unable-to-view-storage-details-in-azure-storage-account-total-data-stored-blo/77924950#77924950

ok, this is fine - but to convert it to count in fileshare? will it work same way?

Yep wait for sometimes it will work.

one more thing: if I use Azure Managed Identity, do I still have to check it's scope regarding this fileshare?

Found solution: this peace of code will do. # Loop through each file share and retrieve quota and usage
foreach ($shareName in $fileShares) {
$usage = Get-AzRmStorageShare -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -Name $shareName -GetShareUsage 
Write-Output  $usage
Write-Output "-----------------------------"

} REF: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/get-azrmstorageshare?view=azps-12.1.0

I'm providing answer with new package

Check the below answer. @Michal Picheta

I have creted this script:
# Import the required Azure modules
Import-Module Az.Accounts
Import-Module Az.Storage
Import-Module Az.Resources

# # Authenticate to Azure
Connect-AzAccount -Identity

# Variables
$env:""
$storageAccountName = ""
$subscriptionId = ""
$storageAccountKey = ""
$resourceGroupName =  ""

# Manage identity check
$connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=$storageAccountName;AccountKey=$storageAccountKey;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"


# Get the storage account context
$storageAccount = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey
$ctx = $storageAccount.Context

# Get the list of file shares
$fileShares = az storage share list --account-name $storageAccountName --query "[].name" -o tsv


# Loop through each file share and retrieve quota and usage
foreach ($shareName in $fileShares) {

    $usage = Get-AzRmStorageShare -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -Name $shareName -GetShareUsage 
    Write-Output  $usage
    Write-Output "-----------------------------"

    
    # Check if usage data is returned
    if ($usage -ne $null) {
        # Extract the ShareUsageBytes property (update the property name if necessary)
        $usageInBytes = $usage.ShareUsageBytes  # Adjust property name as needed

        # Convert bytes to gigabytes
        $usageInGB = $usageInBytes / 1GB

        # Format and output the result
        Write-Output "File Share: $shareName"
        Write-Output "Usage: $([math]::Round($usageInGB, 2)) GB"
        Write-Output "-----------------------------"
    } else {
        Write-Output "No usage data found for file share: $shareName"
    }


}




Get lists of Fileshares in Storage Account
Get total Quota used for every Fileshare
Get Used capacity and display all those data into screen.


You can use the below script to get the list of fileshares with their total quota and Used capacity,
Script:
# Define the storage account details
$accountName = "venkat891"
$accountKey = "xxxxxx"

# Create the storage context
$ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $accountName -StorageAccountKey $accountKey

# Get the list of file shares
$fileShares = Get-AzStorageShare -Context $ctx

# Iterate through each file share and get statistics
foreach ($share in $fileShares) {
    # Get the ShareClient for the current share
    $client = $share.ShareClient
    
    try {
        # Get share properties
        $properties = $client.GetProperties()
        $shareUsageInBytes = $client.GetStatistics().Value.ShareUsageInBytes
        $quotaGB = $properties.Value.QuotaInGB

        # Output the share details
        Write-Output "File Share: $($share.Name)"
        Write-Output "Quota (GB): $quotaGB"
        Write-Output "Used Capcity (bytes):$shareUsageInBytes"
        Write-Output "-----------------------------"
    } catch {
        Write-Output "Failed to get statistics for share: $($share.Name). Error: $_"
    }
}

Output:
File Share: share1
Quota (GB): 102400
Used Capcity (bytes):42787
-----------------------------
File Share: share2
Quota (GB): 102400
Used Capcity (bytes):18690
-----------------------------


Reference:
Get Azure File share size using PowerShell - Stack Overflow by Gaurav Mantri.

IF I use you script I get: "Failed to get statistics for share . Error: You cannot call a method on a non-valued expression.:

Have you tried the same script?

copy - paste your script.

What is the version of powershell in azure runbook?

7.2 latest version

Seems like you could have just marked the question as a duplicate of the one you referenced, instead of copying most of someone else's answer here?
